# Storing JSON as a string in JSON using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

For testing purposes, I wish to use Ajax to request some JSON from the server.  From the Ajax client's perspective, the JSON  should look like:

```
json=[
    {"source":"pa","jsonstring": '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}'},
    {"source":"pa","jsonstring": '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}'},
    {"source":"pa","jsonstring": '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}'}
];
```

Note that `jsonstring` is not JSON, but a string, and `$.getJSON()` should not parse it into an object.

My attempt is below, however, I get error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /var/www/test/src/classes/Ajax.php on line 13`.

How should this be performed?

```
$content=file_get_contents('../buffer.json',true); //Line 13
$buffer=$content?json_decode($content):[];

$json=json_encode(['a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3]);
$buffer[]=[
    'source'=>'pa',
    'jsonstring'=>'"'.$json.'"'
];

$buffer=json_encode($buffer);
file_put_contents('../buffer.json',$buffer);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo($buffer);
```

`buffer.json` output is shown below:

```
[{"source":"pa","jsonstring":"\"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":3}\""},{"source":"pa","jsonstring":"\"{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":3}\""}]
```

Comment: @epascarello  I don't want JSON as the content of `json.jsonstring`, but just a string (which happens to look like JSON, but shouldn't be interpreted as JSON by the browser).

Comment: Are you sure that line 13 is `$content=file_get_contents('../buffer.json',true);`? Can you confirm that?

Comment: @EduardoEscobar  Confirmed.  I added the earlier lines.

Comment: The only comma (`','`) i see in line 13 is within `file_get_contents()` function, and it doesn't seem to be unexpected to me.

Comment: You should not change your code to match an answer given below as then the answer will loose its meaning. If you have additional comments, just put them below the original question.

Comment: I don't think this is a json error, looks like you are trying to parse a string (the php syntax  error), but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Guess *user1032531* may already know where the error was, lol :)

Comment: @jeroen  I didn't change it.  All I did was add the irreverent 12 lines to the beginning so that line 13 showed up as line 13.

Comment: You also removed the quotes around `$json`...

Comment: @NicolasP.  Ugg!  My `true` was in `file_get_contents` instead of `json_decode`.

Comment: @jeroen  Oh, I did not mean to.  I accidentally did when I added the extra lines.  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried removing the extra quotes from `'jsonstring'=>'"'.$json.'"'`? If you json_encode it (which it looks like you do), then it is already a string. I think it should be `'jsonstring' => $json`.

Comment: But that will make jQuery interpret it as JSON which I don't wish to do.  It needs to be interpreted as a string.

Comment: @user1032531 No, you are encoding the `$buffer` object later on so when that gets decoded, the inner encoded strings will still be strings.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a JSON format error, but a syntax error, odd enough i might add.

Comment: Dah, I wasn't thinking.  Thanks